# Use CSS to keep elements from overlapping based on height

Tags: html, css

So I've run into a CSS formatting question that I'm hoping I can get some help with. In general, I've got my setup working, having the position of the menu shift based on the size of the screen so that it is always centered vertically and horizontally, etc.

However, I've run into an issue where if you make the viewing window too small, elements begin to overlap, which is not desired.

Here is a fiddle to display what I am talking about. I would prefer that the green box force everything else below it, so it no longer overlaps the red one (Everything within the "buttonContainerBase" div):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzev3rhw/)

Here's the HTML Div setup and relevant CSS:

```css
#buttonContainerBase {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.hCenterDiv {
  width: 370px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.backgroundBoxDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 244px;
  margin-top: -112px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 370px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  opacity: 0.95;
  filter: alpha(opacity=95);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 45%, #F5F5F5 75%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, color-stop(45%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(75%, #F5F5F5));
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFFFFF 45%, #F5F5F5 75%);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #244260;
}
.logoContainerDiv {
  width: 344px;
  height: 76px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}
.dividingLineDiv {
  height: 2px;
  width: 370px;
  background-color: #335B84;
}
#myLogo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 257px;
  height: 73px;
  background-color: green;
}
#contentWrapper {
  min-height: 300px;
}
.buttonContainerDiv {
  /*padding: 5px;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#studentLoginDiv {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.customButton {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 225px;
  height: 34px;
  border: solid 2px #FFFFFF;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: outset;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.customButton:hover {
  border: solid 2px #F5F5F5;
  border-style: inset;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.customButton:active {
  border: solid 4px #F5F5F5;
  border-style: inset;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentWrapper">
  <div id="buttonContainerBase">
    <div class="hCenterDiv">
      <div class="backgroundBoxDiv">
        <div class="elementContainerDiv">
          <div class="logoContainerDiv"></div>
          <div class="dividingLineDiv"></div>
          <div class="buttonContainerDiv">
            <input class="customButton" id="instructorLogin" type="button" value="Instructor Login" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com');" />
          </div>
          <div class="buttonContainerDiv" id="studentLoginDiv">
            <input class="customButton" id="studentLogin" type="button" value="Student Login" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/');" />
          </div>
          <div class="dividingLineDiv"></div>
          <div class="buttonContainerDiv">
            <input class="customButton" id="instructionalVids" type="button" value="Instructional Videos" onclick="window.open('https://www.youtube.com/');" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="myLogo"></div>
</div>
```

Still kind of new to the CSS game, so I apologize in advance if things look funky/awkward.

Comment: Im not gonna answer your question, but if you are new to the "CSS game" you can skip a lot of learning if you learn flexbox from the start. Then you coul avoid a lot of problems, maybe even this one. I recommended http://flexboxfroggy.com/ to couple backend developers and they enjoyed this educational game. Hope you will find this advice helpful.

Comment: I would have to disagree with @Pavelloz. Learning *all* aspects of CSS will allow you to write your own CSS but also diagnose and fix issues with CSS that other people have written.  Not to say that Flexbox couldn't be the solution here but recommending you *skip a lot of learning* doesn't seem like solid advice to me.

Comment: I'll look into flexbox at some point, but I agree with enki in that there is value in learning a solution, rather than learning how to bypass the problem. I only did this in CSS to learn more about CSS, since it's such a simple concept.

Comment: As someone once said, "Intellectuals solve problems, geniuses prevent them.". Anyway, do what you gotta do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `#myLogo` has `position:absolute`, so :

- change to `position:relative` in CSS
- move the `div` in the DOM to be on the top
- remove all CSS for `#buttonContainerBase`

In `backgroundBoxDiv`

- remove `margin-top: -112px`, that would be somehow a hack.
- add this code:

  ```
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
  ```

**NOTE** This will overlap in 320px view, so you might need media queries for that.

---

```css
.hCenterDiv {
  width: 370px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.backgroundBoxDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  margin:auto;
  height: 244px;
  width: 370px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  /*
 border: solid 2px #004586;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 */
  opacity: 0.95;
  filter: alpha(opacity=95);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 45%, #F5F5F5 75%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, color-stop(45%, #FFFFFF), color-stop(75%, #F5F5F5));
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFFFFF 45%, #F5F5F5 75%);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #244260;
}
.logoContainerDiv {
  width: 344px;
  height: 76px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  /* border: solid 2px #004586; */
}
.dividingLineDiv {
  height: 2px;
  width: 370px;
  background-color: #335B84;
}
#myLogo {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 257px;
  height: 73px;
  background-color: green;
}
#contentWrapper {
  /*
 column-count: 2;
 column-gap: 40px;
 */
  min-height: 300px;
  
}
/******** BUTTONS *********/

.buttonContainerDiv {
  /*padding: 5px;*/
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#studentLoginDiv {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.customButton {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 225px;
  height: 34px;
  border: solid 2px #FFFFFF;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: outset;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.customButton:hover {
  border: solid 2px #F5F5F5;
  border-style: inset;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.customButton:active {
  border: solid 4px #F5F5F5;
  border-style: inset;
  background-color: #D1D1D1;
}
/****** END BUTTONS *******/
```

```html
<div id="contentWrapper">
  <div id="myLogo"></div>
  <div id="buttonContainerBase">
    <div class="hCenterDiv">
      <div class="backgroundBoxDiv">
        <div class="elementContainerDiv">
          <div class="logoContainerDiv"></div>
          <div class="dividingLineDiv"></div>
          <div class="buttonContainerDiv">
            <input class="customButton" id="instructorLogin" type="button" value="Instructor Login" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com');" />
          </div>
          <div class="buttonContainerDiv" id="studentLoginDiv">
            <input class="customButton" id="studentLogin" type="button" value="Student Login" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/');" />
          </div>
          <div class="dividingLineDiv"></div>
          <div class="buttonContainerDiv">
            <input class="customButton" id="instructionalVids" type="button" value="Instructional Videos" onclick="window.open('https://www.youtube.com/');" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer!

I just tried it, and while it does solve the overlapping problem, the menu now no longer centers vertically in the page, just horizontally. I'm thinking I might just solve this with javascript, since what I really need is a way to tell that element, "if element.y < 78 { element.y=78; }". I was just hoping there was a way to keep the full functionality and fix the issue with CSS.

Comment: Well, I tried your updated fix, and while it might be a bit better, the overlap, as you noted is still there. I'll look into media queries, but I may end up just going the javascript route. Either way, thank you for taking the time to look into this.

Comment: @nyghtrunner it is only in 320px,  so a minimum media query would fix that, No need for going for javascript, I just don't think that I have to code everything. I solved your issue, noticing that was a small viewport that need to be taken care of.

Comment: The media query did the trick. And a good deal easier to use than I would have imagined. Thanks again!

Comment: @nyghtrunner don't edit the question to thank me and to add the code you've ended up using instead  you might consider accept the answer :),

Comment: So what, is it just bad form to post the completed code somewhere? Technically, without the media query, yours isn't a fix. I apologize if this is poor etiquette, but I honestly do not understand why you keep reverting my question, and effectively not allowing the community to actually see the completed code.

Comment: Because the question is where you had your issue. If you want to, you can add it but as an answer. BTW mine is the fix because I fixed the main problem and then I advise you to use the media queries, even tell you where would  the layout "break", again it isn't expected to code every single thing. :)